# How do you say I am emailing something and attaching it to the email?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, email

I am usually confused if I am going to use 入れます or 付けます when specifying that I attached something to the email.

For example:

```
最新の帳票サンプルを添付して入れます。
```

or

```
最新の帳票サンプルを添付して付けます。
```

I would usually say that I am usually trying to say that the assigned task is finished the finished output is attached to the mail. Is it more natural to say 付け (attached) or 入れ (in the mail)?

Comment: Besides your point, the two sentences are ungrammatical. 1. You can't use `が` for the object in this case. 2. It is not clear what role `添付に` is playing.

Comment: Yeah, maybe s/he tried to say 最新の帳票サンプルが添付ファイルに入っています/
最新の帳票サンプルが添付ファイルに付けてあります。(but these are still unnatural, no...?)

Comment: @sawa Ok. Correcting the grammar of sample sentence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think we usually use the verb '[添付]{てんぷ}する'.
～を添付します。/～を添付しております。/～を添付させていただいております。etc...
Or maybe you could say 
～を添付ファイルにて送信させていただきます。/～を添付ファイルで送らせていただきます。/～を添付ファイルにて送信させていただきますのでご確認ください。(Hmm, too polite?)

Comment: +1 Can never learn something too polite, all depends on who you're emailing :D

Comment: @crunchyt-san Ah good to hear that, thanks. Yeah most of my examples above might be good for business use.

Comment: What happened to 添付いたします?

Comment: @Bathrobe-san, Oh yes you're right. Then 添付いたしております will also work, no?